# How to start Android SDK manager?

Tags: android, android-sdk

I've installed Android SDK like so:

```
sudo apt-get install android-sdk
```

Now what? How do I start anything? Searching for "Android" doesn't show anything in Gnome Activities. What did installing `android-sdk` even do if there's nothing to run? I do see `adb` at the command line, but that's all.

Comment: The location of the Android SDK Manager is <wherever-you-installed-it>/tools/android.   From a terminal, change to that directory and type ./android

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like the `android-sdk` package for Ubuntu does not come with any `android` file.

Comment: I don't know what the package includes, but you can download the sdk tools directly from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html.  From that, you can select which versions you want (for space reasons) to download.

Comment: no sdkmanager to be found anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but whatever. I stumbled on the same problem and maybe someone can contribute to make it a bit better for whoever comes next.

The `android-sdk` manager does not give you anything to start from, if not the basic libraries and few tools to work with Android (like `adb`).

If you are at this point and don't know what's what, you might want to stop and read a bit more on how the Android development and ecosystem works: using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro) (the IDE based on IntellijIDEA) could be a good starting point.

The `sdkmanager` is (now) part of a different package and it doesn't seem to be shipped through the repos (I guess license issue? or they don't care to package it for debian/ubuntu). You need to download and install it separately [from the official android website](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools).

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was switching into my directory:

```
android-studio/bin
```

Then running the following bash command:

```
./studio.sh
```